# Using value itself without the name of value in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any way to use variable itself inside without it's name?
For example, I have a string like this:
`someStuffVariableName = "abcdefghijklmnop..."`
If I want to manipulate it, I need to write every time name of this var but it's so long:
`someStuffVariableName = someStuffVariableName[0:-1]`
But,anyway,can I do like this:
`someStuffVariableName = self[0:-1]` or `someStuffVariableName = this.value[0:-1]`?

Comment: Reduce the length of the variable name. If you want `this` in python, then you have to use OOPS in python

Comment: aha thanks for answer @bigbounty!

Comment: So, why do you use long identifiers? You do not have to.

Comment: @DYZ I wanted to explain my question with this simple example, I don't want to use it, I just want to way of using variables like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.

Your best options are:

1. Use a more concise variable name (but don't give up readability!)
2. Just deal with the length

Note that in *some* cases, the answer is actually yes. For instance, you can often write `x += y` instead of `x = x + y`, and `x /= y` instead of `x = x / y`.

But this is for [assignment operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_assignment_operators.asp) only.